# Counting non-nesting binary strings

Tags: combinatorics

A binary string $S$ of length $2n$ is said to be non-nesting if there is a perfect matching $M$ between identical bits such that no two edges of $M$ are nesting.

Edges (2, 4) and (1, 6) are nesting (integers represents the location of identical bits inside the string $010110$).

> What is the number of non-nesting binary strings?

Comment: Have you tried computing this for several small values of $n$, then seeing if the answer is in OEIS?

Comment: I only ask because I have no other idea how to proceed.